# LaTeX: Textbox within article

Tags: two-column, shapepar

I'm not completely new to LaTeX but I'm not used to work with special layout schemes, so that's why I thought it was a good idea to post my question here.

Momently I'm trying to create an article witch has a layout as shown in this
[picture](http://img821.imageshack.us/img821/5475/articlez.png): [image: three coloumns, with the two outer surrounding the middle]

But I'm kind off clueless on how to achieve something like that.
Anyone who can push me in the right direction?

Comment: Related/duplicate (more comprehensive): [How do you create pull quotes?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45709/5764); [Implementing a pullquotes algorithm in LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45958/5764)

Answer (score 11):

Such things are not easy with LaTeX, so be warned.
There is the `shapepar` package which allows you to shape paragraphs and also make cutouts. The problem is that you have to make a cutout from both columns!

The following code cuts the same paragraph out twice. Note that the text is set twice but the first time in white. Also you will run into trouble / more required effort if your cutout should span multiple paragraphs in the columns!
Also the second column (which can be switched to with `\newpage` because the two columns are kind of the "pages" on one) need to start with an paragraph. I tried to use `afterpage` (package and macro) to place the second cut-out automatically at the beginning of the second column, but it didn't work. The text was placed correctly but the cutout wasn't done.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{shapepar}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{afterpage}

\title{Twocolumn and parshape}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\cutout {r} (5pt,100pt) \shapepar {\squareshape}
{\color{white}\blindtext}\par
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[4]

\newpage
%\afterpage
\cutout {l} (-5pt,100pt) \shapepar {\squareshape}
\blindtext\par
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

#### Result:

[image: Result]

Comment: +1 Very clever!  Now we just need Aditya to give us the ConTeXt version. ;-)