# Implementing a pullquotes algorithm in LaTeX

Tags: programming

In  [pullquotes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/45733/963), I provided a manual technique for typesetting pullquotes in LaTeX. The technique was to typeset the material in two long narrow columns and then position them so as to join them together. A typical left column would look like the image below.

[image]

I am trying to automate the solution provided by this answer and would like some help **on designing and implementation of the algorithm to achieve it.**

For simplicity, we will assume that the display will be on a full page or that the available space on the page is adequate to hold the text.

The user input is envisaged to be of the following form

```
\begin{pullquote}[_nlines_]{<picturefile>}
...text
\end{pullquote}
```

the optional argument can be extended at a later stage to provide a key value interface to specify the position of the image such as `vcenter`, `top`, `\bottom` `posy` etc.

1. Measure the picture height and width.
2. Translate height of image into baselines.
3. Insert all material in `boxA`.
4. Split `boxA` at *nlines* and store in `boxB`.
5. Insert `\par` on top of `boxB` and compensate for `\parskip` and `lineskip`.
6. Insert `\parshape` or `\hangindent` command to allow for image window.
7. Insert image.
8. Split boxB at end of image, end paragraph.
9. Iterate to add enough material to complete the left column. (This is possibly not reliable).
10. Repeat for right column with cut on left.
11. Position images.
12. Typeset.

In the algorithm, I omitted run-of-the-mill sections for brevity, such as measurements etc. Playground MWE below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,xcolor,graphicx}
\usepackage[latin]{babel}
\newcommand\lorem{Fusce adipiscing justo nec ante. Nullam in enim.
 Pellentesque felis orci, sagittis ac, malesuada et, facilisis in,
 ligula. Nunc non magna sit amet mi aliquam dictum. In mi. Curabitur
 sollicitudin justo sed quam et quadd et quadd. }
\parindent0pt
\def\exampletext{\lipsum}
\fboxsep=0pt
\fboxrule=1pt
\hfuzz=\maxdimen
\def\addgraphic{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{./graphics/amato}}
\raggedright
\begin{document}
\hsize 0.49\linewidth
\setbox3=\vbox{%
\exampletext}
\boxmaxdepth0pt


\setbox1\vsplit3to 8\baselineskip

\setbox1=\vbox{%
   \unvbox1
   \rule{\hsize}{2pt}
   \vskip-\baselineskip
    \leavevmode
    \vbox to -8pt{%
       \hbox to \dimexpr 1.25\hsize{\hfill\addgraphic}
    }
   {{\hangindent-2cm 
      \lorem\par}}
   \lorem
}
\fbox{\box1}
{{\color{purple}\box3}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I played around with the idea a little using a `\insert` with OTR in plain, but a show-stopper for me proved to be my inability to detect paragraphs for `\parshape` (if new paragraphs begin during the area with the insert). It'd be interesting to see how this pans out.

Comment: @morbusg After the first cut, where I put the rule, you do a `leave mode` and you insert a paragraph after the lorem. A hangindent is easier, but then you may end up with a long indented section, you cut again at bottom of image etc..

Comment: I'm not sure about the interface that you propose: what exactly does the begin/end denote; what should happen after the end? is this supposed to be balancing like, say multicols at that point or ...? My feeling is that this is not really providing a syntax for the problem you want to solve.

Comment: @FrankMittelbach The idea is to use as an environment. specify at which line the image starts and where it ends. I don't think balancing of columns will be possible. I am open to other suggestions.

Comment: @Yiannis my point is that I don't see a role for the end of the environment: what should it indicate? One way to look at the pull quotes is that they are async and bound to place on a page and have nothing (or not much) to do with the text another way to look at it is to think of them being bound to text material but then you are having the issue of what to do if that text starts in the second column.

Comment: @FrankMittelbach I see your point and probably easier to implement. Your second suggestion of viewing the pullquote as being fixed on a particular place on the page is attractive, however I am not sure how you would flow the text around it with a TeX engine.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides Just mentioning that my solution **does** balance columns ;-)

Comment: The `flowfram` package (http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/flowfram) might also be relevant to this.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Ok, here's my approach.

The basic idea is to typeset both columns as one box which is split afterwards. The outer form of the text is predefined as one big `\parshape` construct.

The algorithm in more detail:

1. Measure the picture to be included and calculate the number of lines it will occupy, as well as the vertical position where it will be placed.
2. From this, generate a "global" parshape construct covering the *concatenation* of both columns and forming the 'inverse' of the picture shape at the calculated position.
3. Typeset the text in a `\vbox`. The "global" parshape is applied to every paragraph. Note that a single paragraph covering both columns is a possible fringe case.
4. At every occurrence of `\par`, an appropriate prefix is stripped from the "global" parshape construct to reflect the number of lines taken up by the preceding paragraph before re-applying the `\parshape` to the next paragraph. `\prevgraf` gives the number of lines in the preceding paragraph.
5. Split the `\vbox` into two columns which are then arranged with the picture.
6. There is one more complication to be considered: For calculating the parshape, the number of lines in a column has to be known. OTOH, the number of lines cannot be known precisely without knowing the parshape, as this influences the numer of lines neccessary for typesetting the text. Hence, an iterative approach is taken, starting with a rough estimate of the line count and then successively adding to it until the proper line count is reached. This will effectively balance the columns.

### The code

The following is not really implementing an immediately useful functionality, but mainly demonstrating how the goal set by the question can be achieved. For being really applicable to some concrete purpose, the code (in particular for outputting the pullquote structure produced) probably has to be extended (see also "possible extensions" below).

If the following is copied into a file `pullquote.sty`,

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{pullquote}[2012/04/03 EXPERIMENTAL package for typesetting pullquote]

\RequirePackage{microtype}

%-------------------------------------------------------------------
% (1) USER INTERFACE
%-------------------------------------------------------------------

% CONFIGURATION

% Distance between columns.
\newdimen\textcoldist
\textcoldist4mm\relax

% Distance around image.
\newdimen\imgdist
\imgdist4mm\relax

% Width of text column.
\newdimen\textcolwd
\textcolwd\dimexpr.5\linewidth-.5\textcoldist\relax

% Main macro.
% \pullquote{<Text>}{<Image>} will typeset <Text> in two
% (balanced) columns, embedding <Image> in the middle such that
% text 'flows around' the image.
% <Text> should be just text interspersed with \par. No lists,
% displayed math etc. <Image> should be a singular object
% like \includegraphics, but it could as well be a \parbox. Make
% sure the size of the image and the amount of text match such
% that the image can be effectively 'flowed around'.

\newcommand\pullquote[2]
{%
  \begingroup
    % We allow widows and orphans as they would lead to glitches
    % in the paragraph shape.
    \clubpenalty=\z@
    \widowpenalty=\z@
    % Make sure both columns start at the same vertical position. 
    \splittopskip\dimexpr\baselineskip-\dp\strutbox\relax
    % Don't complain about underfull boxes at \vsplit.
    \vbadness\maxdimen
    \vfuzz\maxdimen
    % Put the image into a box which can be measured.
    \setbox\imgbox@pq
    =\hbox{%
      #2%
    }%
    % (2) The text is typeset once to get a rough estimate of the
    % required number of lines.
    \typesettext@pq{#1}{}%
    % Calculate number of lines for text and image.
    \pqlines@pq
    \numexpr
      \dimexpr\ht\textbox@pq+\dp\textbox@pq\relax
      /\baselineskip
      /\tw@
    \relax
    \imglines@pq
    \numexpr
      \dimexpr\ht\imgbox@pq+\dp\imgbox@pq+2\imgdist\relax
      /\baselineskip
    \relax
    % (2a) Column line count is only a rough estimate, not
    % considering the text extension by \parshape. So we \loop
    % until correct column line count is reached.
    \loop
      \typeout{trying \the\pqlines@pq\space lines.}%
      % Calculate number of lines above image.
      \imgtopoffset@pq
      \numexpr(\pqlines@pq-\imglines@pq)/\tw@\relax
      % Number of lines in parshape.
      \global\parshapelines@pq\numexpr2*\pqlines@pq+\@ne\relax
      % (3) Calculate "global" parshape from image size and position.
      \xdef\parshape@pq
      {%
        \number\parshapelines@pq\space
        \iterate@mkps@pq{1}{1}%
        0pt\space\the\textcolwd\space
      }%
      % (4) Re-typeset text with parshape setting.
      \typesettext@pq{#1}
      {%
        \let\o@par\par
        \let\par\par@pq
        \parshape\parshape@pq
      }%
      % (6) Split off two columns.
      \setbox\columnabox@pq=\vsplit\textbox@pq to \pqlines@pq\baselineskip
      \setbox\columnbbox@pq=\vsplit\textbox@pq to \pqlines@pq\baselineskip
      % (7) Iterate until estimation for  column line count is correct.
     \unless\ifvoid\textbox@pq
      % We need to advance line count by half the "leftover" lines
      % in \textbox@pq. To make sure we're not over-extending the
      % line count (by any strange effect of line breaking with
      % the changed parshape) which could lead to unneccessary
      % white space at the bottom of the right column, we deduce
      % one from the result. 
      \@tempcnta
      \numexpr
        \dimexpr\ht\textbox@pq+\dp\textbox@pq\relax
        /\baselineskip
        /\tw@
        -\@ne
      \relax
      % But advance line count by at least one.
      \ifnum\@tempcnta<\@ne\@tempcnta\@ne\fi
      \advance\pqlines@pq\@tempcnta
    \repeat
    % (8) Output text columns and image.
    \hbox
    {%
      \rlap
      {%
        \hskip
        \dimexpr
          \textcolwd+.5\textcoldist-.5\wd\imgbox@pq
        \relax
        \raise
        \dimexpr
          \numexpr\pqlines@pq-\imglines@pq-\imgtopoffset@pq\relax
          \baselineskip
          +.5\dimexpr\imglines@pq\baselineskip-\ht\imgbox@pq-\dp\imgbox@pq\relax
        \relax
        \box\imgbox@pq
      }%
      \box\columnabox@pq\hskip\textcoldist\box\columnbbox@pq
    }%
  \endgroup
}

%-------------------------------------------------------------------
% INTERNALS
%-------------------------------------------------------------------

% AUXILIARY REGISTERS AND CONTAINERS.

% Box for full text content.
\newbox\textbox@pq
% Box for first column.
\newbox\columnabox@pq
% Box for second column.
\newbox\columnbbox@pq
% Box for image.
\newbox\imgbox@pq
% Line count for one column.
\newcount\pqlines@pq
% Line count for "global" parshape.
\newcount\parshapelines@pq
% Line count for image.
\newcount\imglines@pq
% Vertical position of image.
\newcount\imgtopoffset@pq
% Container for "global" parshape definition.
\newcommand*\parshape@pq{}

% INTERNAL MACROS.

% Typeset text. Some precautions are made for keeping register.

\newcommand\typesettext@pq[2]%
{%
  \setbox\textbox@pq
  =\vbox{%
    \hsize\textcolwd
    \tolerance9999\relax
    \lineskiplimit-\maxdimen
    \parskip\z@
    % Here the parshape settings can be injected.
    #2%
    \strut#1%
  }%
}%

% (3) Generate parshape lines. This is a very naive definition which just
% clips out the image box, but it could easily be made much more general.

\newcommand\iterate@mkps@pq[2]%
{%
  \ifnum\numexpr#1*#2\relax>\numexpr2*\pqlines@pq\relax
   \else
    \ifnum#1>\pqlines@pq
      \iterate@mkps@pq{1}{2}%
     \else
      \ifnum#1>\imgtopoffset@pq
         \ifnum#1>\numexpr\imgtopoffset@pq+\imglines@pq\relax
           0pt\space\the\textcolwd\space
          \else
           \ifnum#2=\@ne
             0pt\space\the
             \dimexpr\textcolwd-.5\wd\imgbox@pq-\imgdist+.5\textcoldist\relax
             \space
            \else
             \the
             \dimexpr.5\wd\imgbox@pq+\imgdist-.5\textcoldist\relax
             \space
             \the
             \dimexpr\textcolwd-.5\wd\imgbox@pq-\imgdist+.5\textcoldist\relax
             \space
           \fi
         \fi
       \else
         0pt\space\the\textcolwd\space
       \fi
       \expandafter\iterate@mkps@pq\expandafter
       {\number\numexpr#1+\@ne\relax}{#2}%
     \fi
   \fi
 }

% (5) Internal definition of \par.
% Truncate "global" parshape by \prevgraf and reassign parshape.

\def\par@pq
{%
  \o@par
  \@tempcnta\prevgraf
  \ifnum\parshapelines@pq<\@tempcnta\@tempcnta\parshapelines@pq\fi
  \global\advance\parshapelines@pq-\@tempcnta
  \ifnum\parshapelines@pq=\z@
   \else
    \xdef\parshape@pq{\expandafter\gobbleparshapeprefix@pq\parshape@pq}%
    \parshape\parshape@pq
  \fi
}

% (5a) Gobble parshape lines.

\def\gobbleparshapeprefix@pq#1 #2 #3 %
{%
  \ifnum#1>\parshapelines@pq
    \expandafter\gobbleparshapeprefix@pq\number\numexpr#1-\@ne\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\relax\expandafter\space
   \else
    #1 #2 #3 %
  \fi
}
```

then it can be used as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum,xcolor,graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[latin]{babel}

\usepackage{pullquote}

\newcommand\alltext
{%
  \lipsum[1-3]
}

\def\addgraphic{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{mill}}
\def\addquote
{%
  \Large
  \begin{tabular}[b]{p{5cm}}
    \midrule
    \textit{Wir müssen wissen.}\\
    \textit{Wir werden wissen.}\\
    \mbox{}\hfill\large\textsc{David Hilbert}\\
    \midrule
  \end{tabular}%
}

\begin{document}
\pullquote{\alltext}{\addgraphic}
\pullquote{\lipsum[1-2]}{\addquote}
\end{document}
```

### Explanation of the code

I commented the code, so I'll only describe the most important steps here. The following items correspond to marks I put in the comments above.

- (1) **User interface.**
  There is only one user-level macro: `\pullquote{`*text*`}{`*quote*`}` will typeset *text* in two columns, inserting *quote* (which must be a rectangular object like `\includegraphics`, `tabular` or `\parbox`) in the middle, such that the text of the columns 'flows around' it. The dimension register `\textcolwd` gives the width of one column, `\textcoldist` gives the distance between columns, and `\imgdist` sets the distance on all sides of the image. Note that the vertical distance of the image can differ because the vertical size of (image+distance) has to be a multiple of `\baselineskip`.
- (2) **Estimating the number of lines.** The whole construction depends on knowing the number of lines in a column (stored in `\pqlines@pq`). But this number cannot be known before actually typesetting the text with the 'window' for the image. To solve this problem, first the text is typeset withot parshape, setting `\pqlines@pq` to (*height* + *depth*)/`\baselineskip`/2. This will be too low for sure (not considering the white space left for the quote) and will be adapted in the following by a `\loop` construct (2a).
- (3) **Calculating the global parshape.** This is done by the macro `\iterate@mkps@pq{`*line*`}{`*col*`}`. It will simply advance *line* twice from 1 to `\pqlines@pq`, once for *col*=1 and once for *col=2*, denoting the column produced. While *col*=1, the parshape represents the left part of the window, while *col*=2, the right part. Hence, `\parshapelines@pq`=`\pqlines@pq`*2 lines in TeXs `\parshape` syntax are produced, all in one sequence. Note that it is a valid fringe case that a single paragraph runs completely through both columns, so we need an appropriately "large" parshape anyway. In fact, one more parshape line is generated at the end, representing a 'full' line, just to be sure we don't get a distorted line count in case the image should go all the way to the bottom.
- (4) **Typesetting in earnest.** Now, we can apply the `\parshape` to get the final form of the text. `\par` is redefined to `\par@pq` which will modify and re-apply the `\parshape` at every new paragraph. Note that at this point, both columns are 'glued together' in one `\vbox` which is later split with `\vsplit`. Note further that by the line count estimation, the box will inevitably be longer than `\pqlines@pq`*2, hence some text will be left over after splitting off the columns.
- (5) **Internal definition of `\par`.** We need to renew the `\parshape` after every paragraph. `\prevgraf` gives the line count of the previous paragraph. We subtract this number from `\parshapelines@pq`, and truncate a corresponding prefix from the parshape construct. (5a) This is done by the macro `\gobbleparshapeprefix@pq`. It just successively reads (and throws away) the first line definition until the number of lines in the parshape (declared as usual by the first number in the construct) reaches the new value of `\parshapelines@pq`.
- (6) **Splitting off columns.** We simply split the text box `\textbox@pq` twice with `\vsplit`, giving two boxes containing one column each.
- (7) **Balancing columns.** Until the line count estimate in `\pqlines@pq` is correct, there will be some material left in `\textbox@pq` after splitting. We use the size of the material to estimate the new line count. But there is a risk here. If we really advance `\pqlines@pq` by the number of lines left over divided by 2, it could get too large. Paragraph formatting is a tricky procedure, and the total line number of the text might well be *reduced* simply by the window being in a different position relative to the lines of the text content. Hence, as a measure of safety, we advance `\pqlines@pq` by (the number of lines left over divided by 2) *minus 1*, but at least by 1. Afterwards, the procedure is repeated from step (2a).
- (8) **Constructing the output.** As soon as `\textbox@pq` is void after splitting, all the text material is in the column boxes. These are combined with the appropriately raised quote in a `\hbox` which forms the result of the macro `\pullquote`.

### Restrictions

1. This is for text interspersed by `\par` only. No lists, no displayed math and effectively no tables.
2. Every line has to be exactly the same height. No changes of `\baselineskip` or large objects inside the text.
3. No stretchable or shrinkable vertical space; in fact vertical spaces are not considered at all.
4. Widows and orphans are not considered, hence they are allowed here.

### Possible exensions

1. The idea of "global parshape" can support much more than just positioning one image. In principle, an arbitrary number of objects (even with non-rectangular shape) could be positioned in different places with a reasonable extension of the parshape calculation.
2. More than one column would also be no problem, ideally in the contenxt of a generalization like the previous item.
3. Page breaks would also be possible, which in priciple calls for some scheme of globally positioning objects on the page with text flowing around them.
4. Once the level of the previous item is reached, all this could be integrated with the output routine, giving a rather non-standard TeX document class - much less freedom *inside* the vertical list and much more freedom for global page layout.

### Result

[image: pullquote example]

### A more advanced example

My *data based publishing* software DocScape more or less implements extension 3 listed above. DocScape has an 'object-oriented' page model allowing to place arbitraty (also irregularly formed) objects on the page. Internally, an explicit "design grid" is kept for every page including allocation of grid cells occupied by  objects which have already been placed. It's a basic property of text frames in DocScape that text can 'flow' around allocated grid cells, using an algorithm similar to the one used above.

Here is a slightly more sophisticated example done with DocScape.

[image: DocScape example]

Examples of "real world" uses of this feature in DocScape projects are found [here](http://www.epd.de/sites/default/files/pdf/epd-Ost-Wochenspiegel_2011_35.pdf) (for instance page 44) and also [here](http://www.wolfcraft.de/workarea/supplier/sWolfcraft/documents/Leaflets/Hauptkatalog_2012_de.pdf) (Warning: 7.3MB) (page 16).

### Update

There is now a package [pullquote](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/%7Etex-sx/tex-sx/development/view/head:/pullquote.dtx) which allows to create circular as well as rectangular inserts.

See [Two-column text with circular insert](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/70169/12850).

Comment: Impressive documents. Does DocScape use a TeX engine?

Comment: It's a TeX macro package based on `pdftex`. Which means I have to cope with font encodings :-( But it's hard to find a good time for migrating to LuaTeX without getting into branch hell...

Comment: XMLTeX. Don't ask, the decision is lost in the mist of time ;-)

Comment: That's akin to alchemy:)

Comment: @YiannisLazarides Ok here's my approach.

Comment: @StephanLehmke for 10 years I thought no one had ever used xmltex and then this year I find that there are several people using it in commercial contexts, and again in your comment here. Strange how things work out:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I think it was Sebastian when I was telling him about it at the TUG conference in HAWAI'I who assured me I must be mad to do so (he was laughing out loud I think). I fail to understand why exactly, but then I'm not really an expert in these things. At least it seems to be fairly efficient. We're having no problems processing nearly 1GB XML data files without significant total slowdown (as long as you avoid certain things).

Comment: Sebastian has no right to laugh, he's responsible for xmltex's creation:-)

Comment: What package is able to do something like your cow example or like http://i.imgur.com/MsbsOVG.png or http://i.imgur.com/Apq8kdv.png or http://i.imgur.com/GxllBgA.png easier? I mean automatically wrapping around a shape without manually specifying coordinates for each line.

Comment: @skan for an image like the cow, that would require analysing the image in TeX, nothing I'd ever try to program and except for perhaps Bruno I don't think anyone would ever try to code this.

Answer (score 4):

Does the [`cutwin`](http://ctan.org/pkg/cutwin) package help at all? It lets you put something (a graphic, a quote, a ...) in a window in a single paragraph.

Comment: Please elaborate on your answer. i.e. show us how to apply it with an example.

Comment: Invoking `texdoc cutwin` will give you the full documentation.