# ┓- shaped figure and caption

Tags: floats, positioning, captions, floatrow

I have a (float) figure that has a ┓-shape, that is there is a huge blank square at the bottom left.

[image]

I'd like to put in this blank the caption of the figure. Is there a way?

My class loads `caption` and `floatrow` packages, so I need something that works with `floatrow`.

Comment: This seems somehow related to pullquotes: [Implementing a pullquotes algorithm in LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45958) Can you make a small example with the `floatrow` package? What happens when TikZ is used?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I have the same problems with the TikZ solution using floatrow. Reported here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139174/problem-using-tikz-with-a-caption-and-floatrow-together

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about using TikZ and write your caption over the image?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
     \node [draw=black, anchor=south west] at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{fig1}};

     \node [draw=black, anchor=south west, text width=.3\textwidth] at (0,0) {\caption{A picture of a X.}};
    \end{tikzpicture} 
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

A *`\RawFloats`* after *`\begin{figure}`* [solves the problem with floatrow](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/139174/8425).

Comment: Sorry, but for some reason (?), it does not work with `floatrow` (which is a requierement).

Comment: Instead of a manual `minipage`, you can also use `text width=.3\textwidth` and let TikZ use its internal version of the `minipage` environment (which is the same for LaTeX).

Answer (score 5):

Here's a very basic, feasible implementation that inserts the caption at the desired location:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\newsavebox{\graphicsbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
  \savebox{\graphicsbox}{\includegraphics[width=.7\linewidth]{myfigure}}% Store image
  \leavevmode\rlap{\usebox{\graphicsbox}}% Set image with complete overlap
  \begin{minipage}[b]{.5\wd\graphicsbox}% Insert caption
    \caption{This is my caption. It has a large amount of information, and should
      flow over several lines.}
  \end{minipage}\hspace*{.5\wd\graphicsbox}% Add space to represent figure width
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The image is set in a box `\graphicsbox` in order to calculate its width. This width is used to measure the `minipage` and subsequent spacing. A `[b]`ottom-placement ensures that the caption is stacked vertically as it expands. The alignment of the `minipage` and surrounding spacing can be changed, of course. For example, to add a `\columnsep` gap between the caption and the image, use

```
\begin{minipage}[b]{\dimexpr.5\wd\graphicsbox-\columnsep}% Insert caption
  % <caption>
\end{minipage}\hspace*{\dimexpr.5\wd\graphicsbox+\columnsep}% Add space to represent figure width
```

Answer (score 4):

I made a two-line change to `boxhandler`'s macro `\ReciteFigure`, and set of few of the package parameters.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{boxhandler}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\ReciteFigure[6][ht]{%
  \begin{figure}[#1]%
    \begin{\LRFigurePlacement}%
      \let\@makecaption\new@makecaption%
      \setlength\abovecaptionskip{\arabic{abovecaptionskipterm}\p@}%
      \setlength\belowcaptionskip{\arabic{belowcaptionskipterm}\p@}%
        \set@DataBoxWidth{#3}%
        \setlength\CaptionBoxWidth{#4}%
        \set@BoxOffsets%
        \if T#6%
          \rule{\@DataBoxOffset}{0in}%
          \makebox[\@DataBoxWidth][l]{#5}%
          \rule{\@DataBoxOffset}{0in}\\%
        \fi
        \rule{\@DataBoxOffset}{0in}%
        \usebox{#3}%
        \rule{\@DataBoxOffset}{0in}%
        \par%
        \rule{\@CaptionBoxOffset}{0em}%
        \parbox{.5\CaptionBoxWidth}{\bx@caption{#2}}% .5 WAS ADDED
        \hspace{.5\CaptionBoxWidth}%                  THIS LINE WAS ADDED
        \rule{\@CaptionBoxOffset}{0em}%
        \if T#6%
          \rule{\@DataBoxOffset}{0in}\\%
          \makebox[\@DataBoxWidth][r]{#5}%
          \rule{\@DataBoxOffset}{0in}%
        \fi
      \let\@makecaption\old@makecaption%
      \setlength\abovecaptionskip\oldabovecaptionskip%
      \setlength\belowcaptionskip\oldbelowcaptionskip%
    \end{\LRFigurePlacement}%
  \end{figure}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\setcounter{abovecaptionskipterm}{-80}
\captionStyle{n}{c}
\def\CaptionJustification{\raggedright}
\bxfigure{My caption goes here and may exceed one line}
{\fbox{\rule{2in}{0in}\rule{0in}{2in}}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting, thanks. I did not know the `boxhandler` package. For my use case, I'd like to stick to `floatrow`.