# Caption within a figure?

Tags: captions

I have an image

[image]

where as x are 3 diagrams. As there is empty space on the left, I was wondering if it is possible to put the caption of the image within the picture.

Comment: short answer: yes, longer answer it depends on the document class and packages you are you are using, and how they set up captions, but you have given no hint about that.

Comment: ...therefore: Please provide a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: Related/duplicate: [┓- shaped figure and caption](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/139091/5764)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a solution which does not assume any package besides `graphicx` for including the images. The `$` around the last figure is to ensure the vertical centering of the caption.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mwe}
\def\image{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image-a}}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\image\hfill\image\par
\vskip 5mm
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.45\textwidth}
\caption{This is the caption, it may be long}
\end{minipage}\hfill%
$\vcenter{\hbox{\image}}$\par
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: I thought the OP has a single image and wants to overlay the caption over the bottom left corner (although that isn't clear:-) but my comment about depending on the package was that some classes position the caption in the float handler irrespective of where `\caption` appears in the source.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I thought about the "single image" interpretation after posting my answer and looking at the "related question" comment. I didn't think about the other problem you mention. Thanks for clarification.