# Easier way of placing a figure over and between columns

Tags: multicol, wrapfigure, wrap

I'd like to reproduce a three-column document which contains figures that span the middle column and also protrude slightly into the left and right columns.  The text wraps around the figure.  Here's an example which was fairly simple to mock up in a word processor:

[image: A three-column document containing a figure that spans the middle column and also extends slightly into the left and right columns, with the text wrapping around the figure.]

The `wrapfig` package contains some relatively obscure instructions, not in the main documentation but tucked away in the text file [`multiple-span.txt`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/wrapfig/multiple-span.txt), which explain how to do this manually.  The process is somewhat tedious.  However, that documentation dates from 2003.  I was wondering whether, in the intervening 12 years, anyone has come up with a more convenient way of doing this.

Comment: [Somebody already listened to your wish](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/70169/11232)

Comment: AFAICT, the pullqoute package only supports two columns, not three, nor can I find it to load.  I did find the source code in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45958/implementing-a-pullquotes-algorithm-in-latex