# How do I put text around a picture in irregular lengths?

Tags: graphics, wrap

First time asking a question because I really couldn't find one similar.
I have a background picture which is a paper texture + a graphic on the bottom right corner. The reason for this, is because the rest of the document uses a paper texture as background and if I crop my image it will not look good. Furthermore, I cannot make the image transparent because I hadn't plan for it.

I used the `tikz` package to change the background image on the page I wanted, and it seemed to work. The text of course is now over the picture. So I want to format it. For info, this is what I used to change the background.

```
\tikz[remember picture,overlay] 
\node[opacity=0.3,inner sep=0pt] at (current page.center){\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{paper_iso.jpg}}; 
\clearpage
```

Then I used `\\` and `\noindent` to manually go around the edges of the picture that is at the bottom right corner. The result looks like this.

[image]

At this moment I need to mention that this is a two column document. The moment I try to do more `\\` and `\noindent` to continue with this method, the background image is pushed to the next page. So here is the question. How does one do such wraps around images? It cannot be that I manually have to add `\\` all over the 6 or so paragraphs.

To sum up, I cannot figure out how to wrap around such an image, and said image is basically the whole background. So I need to wrap around only at the bottom right of the page without the who background being pushed to the next. There must be a way, since I have seen so many documents that are clearly written in LaTeX doing such things.

P.S. A normal float wouldn't work I think, since I cannot have it quadratic.

Thanks a lot in advance for any help you many provide.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45958/implementing-a-pullquotes-algorithm-in-latex

Comment: Or https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/68740/227987.