# Positioning image between two columns

Tags: positioning, multicol, wrapfigure, wrapfig

I need to place an image in the two column text like on the next picture:

[image: source]

I've tried `wrapfig` package to make it:

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\blindtext[3]
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}[50pt]{0.25\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{deco}
\end{wrapfigure}
\blindtext[2]
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

But it wraps the text only in one of the columns:

[image: result]

How it can be done correctly?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53073/two-column-text-with-circular-insert

Comment: This might be helpful: [Implementing a pullquotes algorithm in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45958)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, thank you very much, I used one of the answers with `\parshape` explanation and it solved my problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Implementing a pullquotes algorithm in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45958/implementing-a-pullquotes-algorithm-in-latex)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, no, I used the second answer from here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53073/two-column-text-with-circular-insert

Comment: ok can you vote to close as duplicate of that one, thanks